# How does Internet Explorer 8 support the CSS outline attribute?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

The [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082(VS.85).aspx) says it's supported however the following style does not render.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        a[href="#"]{outline:#f00 dotted 2px !important}
    </style>
```

however, the following will render

```
    <style type="text/css">
        a[href="#"]{border:#f00 dotted 2px !important}
    </style>
```

Here is my document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>...</title>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../content/style.css" />

</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that rule gets applied? I think IE8 does support attribute selectors (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), but that'd be worth checking.

Comment: it is supported only in standards mode... what rendering mode is your page in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check whether IE8 is rendering in a compliant mode. If you have something like the following in the your header, then outline will not work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

IE8 will also default to quirks mode if your doctype tag is incorrect, so verify this as well. Also, if you're using IIS, it's possible that the server is forcing IE7 compatibility mode.

Comment: I've add the head of my document to my original question. It is xhtml 1.0 strict and it validates

Comment: that was it, i had compatibility mode turned on

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because the link does not appear in the browser as `#` but as `yourpage.html#`

Try using ends-with instead:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a[href$="#"]{outline:#f00 dotted 2px !important}
</style>
```

Comment: Border is not the same as outline. He's just pointing out that the selector that he's using works for his purposes.