# How to soften an html border color (not to be so opaque)

Tags: html, css, styles, client-side

I want to put a boder colored onto a textbox, but the color i get is too intense and opaque:

I get this border:

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

My simple ccs is:

```
.highlitedborder
{
   border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
```

The last alpha value (0.5) can be seen as opacity.

By the way, what u see in the image is not border. It is closer to box-shadow
(that effect is created by browser in some case)

```
box-shadow: 0 0 4px orange;
```

Comment: Even the best developers have a hard time styling for < IE8. My approach is to just get the functionality up and forget the styling. It's user base is small, and majority is with Chrome, Firefox and IE9.

Answer (score 2):

This part is not the border. It is the outline. You may change it to change it it like

```
    .highlitedborder
{
   outline-color: your color...or your style;
}
```

Comment: Is there cross-browser way to simulate the outline-color?

Comment: @senyortoni I searched for it and i got this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537968/how-does-internet-explorer-8-support-the-css-outline-attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
border: 1px solid #e68200
```

This can help you