# Infamous "outline: none;" issue within IE(8)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, outline

http://www.massgeneral.org/international/dev/content-wrap.aspx

I'm attempting to remove the outline boxes that are created when clicking the anchors tags (Arrows and Thumbnails) within a UI I've built.  I've set the "outline: none;" to all the anchor elements tortured by this border issue.  The style is being pulled into the selectors for the anchor elements within IE, however, the outlines are still being generated when a user clicks one of the elements.

http://oi50.tinypic.com/2mfxfg2.jpg

**Any advice?**

```
div#wrap a, div#wrap a:focus, div#wrap a:active,
div#wrapWrap a, div#wrapWrap a:focus, div#wrapWrap a:active {outline: none !important;}
```

I do apologize ahead of time as I'm aware this question has been answered on several discussions. However, after doing research, it appears I'm following the proper procedures to resolve this issue.  Unfortunately, the issue is still occurring within my implementation.

Please only test this issue within IE8 or greater,
Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line in your `<head>` element is biting you:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538066/1128047), you need to remove that line to disable IE7 emulation mode. Note also that if you're running on IIS, the server itself can force this emulation mode (so check that also, if removing this doesn't solve the problem). Also, make sure your `doctype` is set appropriately.

Comment: Jonah, thanks so much for your response. Unfortunately, I'm not in control of the overall base of the website used on massgeneral.org. Now that I understand that it's a conflicting issue with the EmulateIE7 content type, I can report this as an IS bug instead of a styling bug.

Comment: Would you happen to have any documentation on why the IE=EmulateIE7 conflicts with the outline: none attribute? I would love to read up on it and understand the entire situation better for communicating a possible upgrade of our content type with our IS department.

Comment: I don't have any specific documentation, but I think IE7 simply didn't support outline. See [this page](http://www.cssjunction.com/css/remove-dotted-border-in-ie7/) for a hack to get around the issue.

Comment: Using the `* { _noFocusLine: expression(this.hideFocus=true); }` Did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually that dotted outline is an accessibility feature (for those that cannot, or choose not to, use a mouse) that is built into IE.  Really it probably shouldn't be removed, and, honestly, doesn't really wreck your layout or anything.  But if you must remove it maybe one of these links will help you out:

- [Here](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Removing-Dotted-Border-on-Clicked-Links)
- [Here](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)
- [Or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142819/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-active-hyperlinks-in-ie8-with-css)

Comment: Thanks! I really enjoyed reading all of these articles. I will report back if I'm able to find a work around the Browser Emulation mode Jonah pointed out.