# datepicker border all td excepts for today

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker and trying to customize.

I want to change the border of the elements, and I have problems with td

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar td{

     border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}



.ui-datepicker-today {

      border: 1px solid #C90212 !important;
}
```

The internal code for datepicker:

```
 /*not today*/
 <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>

 /*Today */
 <td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">9</a></td>
```

The problem is the border top for today is not setting.

I tried with border-spacing but it doesnt work with internet explorer.

I attach an image with the result
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using outline instead of border?

Comment: It doesnt work in IE

Comment: I'm not sure how far back in IE you want to support, but looks like at least back to IE 8 supports it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=outline

Comment: it is said but it is not working in IE8 either in IE11, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537968/how-does-internet-explorer-8-support-the-css-outline-attribute but the answer doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css to:

```
.ui-datepicker-today a {
  border: 1px solid #C90212 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the color of the edges must change the `a` in the `td`, and looks like this:

```
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight{
   border: 1px solid #C90212 !important;
}
```

Comment: how can I this fix the cell? it puts a border arround the number, but I want to border the cell